# Serializing XML data to store in MySQL with PHP

Tags: php, mysql, xml, serialization, storage

I have a series of very complex XML files.  I need to access these often, so reading .xml files is something of a hangup.  I've been considering writing a series of massive SQL statements, but before I begin that massive task, I wanted to know about serializing whole XML files to store as blobs in MySQL.

```
My intentions: 
XML -> store_into_database()
database -> read_seralized_data($row)
echo -> un_serialize_data($row)
```

This would allow me to store .xml files that I parse from an onlinedatabse, and only have to do I/O operations once.

or is the the wrong way to do this?

Comment: I have about 30k xml files, each can go as high as about 400kb, but average about 100kb.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

XML is a conspiracy foisted on the world by storage manufacturers seeking to increase their profits by making all data bloat exponentially in size by xmling it all. It's crap as a storage/retrieval format, with both massive storage and parsing overhead.

Since you need to access these xml files often, you'd be better off converting them into a native SQL table structure so you can use actual DB operations, indexing, etc... on them. If you're lucky, maybe you've got a DB that can handle XML natively, and you should take advantage of that. otherwise you're stucking retrieving a blob, unserializing the blob, feeding that blob into a DOM parser, then doing DOM operations, each and every time you need to check if the sky is still blue.

Comment: Well, I _CAN_ fetch the .xml files as .json files.  And I'm not sure how to tell if my database can handle xml naively.  I mean, it's MySQL.  And is retrieving a blob, unserializing it, then feeding it to a DOM paraser really that bad?  Those operations seem to be speedy enough.  'smore light if ye will m'lord.

Comment: For a one-time retrieval, it's fine, but exactly how often is your "often". a few times an hour? hundreds of times a second? Consider that fetch/unserialize/dom-parse/dom-search will be 90% of your average 'fetch a single value' run, 90% overhead very quickly becomes very expensive.

Comment: Yeah, it'd be hundreds of times a second.  

My biggest concern is how on earth do I go about building a full .xml file into a database?  There are anywhere from 25-50 elements, some of them would require tables each for their own data.  (One element holds a series of screenshots.)  How do realprogrammers do this?  Certainly they don't make 100-line MySQL query calls?